# Module path issue while trying to run Go Echo app in docker

Tags: docker, go

I am having a weird issue to run a [Go Echo Framework](https://echo.labstack.com/). It works fine when I use the `docker run` command, that is no dependency issue and it executes the file properly but while running `docker-compose up` it gives error:

```
Creating echo_app ... done
Attaching to echo_app
echo_app | server.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/labstack/echo/v4" in any of:
echo_app |  /usr/local/go/src/github.com/labstack/echo/v4 (from $GOROOT)
echo_app |  /go/src/github.com/labstack/echo/v4 (from $GOPATH)
echo_app exited with code 1
```

Below are my files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.15-alpine
LABEL maintainer="Me"

RUN apk update
RUN apk add git

# Setting up Dev environment
RUN mkdir /echo_app
COPY . /echo_app/
WORKDIR /echo_app/

# Download Echo Framework with help of Go mod (Credit: https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1374#issuecomment-559990790)
# Init to create Go Module
RUN go mod init app.com/main
# Building to download echo framework and other dependencies
RUN go build

# RUN the server
#CMD go run server.go 
EXPOSE 1323
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services: 
  web:
    container_name: echo_app
    image: echo_app:latest
    build: ./
    command: go run server.go
    volumes:
      - .:/echo_app
    ports: 
      - "1323:1323"
```

Comment: I cant reporoduce your error. Are you sure you've runs `docker-compose up` without cache? Try to rebuild it `docker-compose down && docker-compose rm` and then `docker-compose up --build`.

Comment: @Зелёный this is how I built `docker build -t echo_app:latest -f Dockerfile .`

and then ran `docker-compose up`. No I am not using cache parameter.

Comment: Running your command gave the error: WARNING: Network echo_docker_default not found.
ERROR: No such service: and

Comment: Why you run `build` with docker but `run` with `docker-compose`?

Comment: @Зелёный this should not make difference? Even I tried your commands it gave network error.

Comment: @Зелёный I removed all trackers of existing images and thing yet the same error. I directly ran `docker-compose --build`.

Comment: There is no such command `docker-compose --build`, `docker-compose build` exists or `docker-compose up --build`.

Comment: @Зелёный sorry that was typo. Yes `docker-compose up build` it but still gives error  ` cannot find package "github.com/labstack/echo/v4" in any of:` but when I attach the shell with the container and run the command `go run server.go` it works perfecttly

Comment: Try `docker-compose build --no-cache`.

Comment: @Зелёный Ok  I noticed something weird. In the host terminal folder I ran `go mod init..` and `go build`. After doing this doing `docker-compose up` worked fine. It seems file not being fetched?

Comment: Some layer cached and you've got missing file. There is also `.dockerignore` maybe.

Comment: you mean some unknown containers/images?

Comment: I mean the docker cache all layers(commands from Dockerfile) and then you invoke `docker-compose up` it's just use cached version but if you change some file docker will build image without cache. Something like that.

Comment: @Зелёный I believe there is some file copying issue. I even restarted docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM golang:1.15-alpine
LABEL maintainer="Me"


# Setting up Dev environment

WORKDIR /echo_app/
# note this file, go.mod exists locally. and contain reference 
# to direct/indirect dependencies. this step allows to download 
# dependencies and speedup build for docker images (if it used 
# to build artifacts, and not as dev env).  
COPY go.mod  /echo_app/go.mod
RUN go mod download


EXPOSE 1323
```

Comment: The issue I am having right now is. When I use the `docker run` command it executes file OK. But only issue is having when using `docker-compose` somehow it is not finding fie. And if I run the go commands in host terminal and then use `docker-compose up` it works just fine. But I do not wan to assume that Go exists in host machine thus want everything GO related within Docker.

Comment: I removed the duplicate `COPY` command but even removing it did not work for me. I used `--cache` too.

Comment: You might want to delete image, and run it with commented out last `COPY ...` to debug it, as you quite possible was copping build artifact. You calso can specify build (context & dockerfile) explicitly.

Comment: trust me imaged removed multiple times. I am on Docker on Mac. Does this work for you? I had already removed COPY command and existing images and containers

Comment: do you "go mod download?"

Comment: even I am lost LOL. Actually I am trying to dockerize this https://echo.labstack.com/guide. If it was a `Dockerfil` issue then running the command `docker run --rm -it  -p 1323:1323/tcp echo_app:latest` should not have worked too but  when I do this, I can get into the folder and all `go.*` files are there. The command the docker-compose should run successfully is `go run server.go` which files when I do docker-compose up not not via interactive shell.

Comment: you go files are there because you have mount directory there. your dockerfile is weird. check my answer in one minute, I will need to edit an answer to place mine docekrfile.

Comment: waiting for what? I have updated my answer with docker files that downloads your dependency. and can `go run server.go`